# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: java, spring, osgi, osgi-bundle

i have bean which implement org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationPlugin ,
creating bean in spring context like below,

```
<bean id="configurationPlugin" class="com.test.plugin.DecryptionConfigurationPlugin">
</bean>
```

but while deploying it,getting below error

```
unsatisfied dependencies: none org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#4': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPlugin' defined in URL [bundle://149.0:0/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:325)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:290)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPlugin' defined in URL [bundle://149.0:0/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OsgiServiceFactoryBean.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:284)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:282)
at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:116)
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1205)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:186)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 22 common frames omitted
```

can anyone help me why i am getting this error,i am using spring version 3.2.14_RELEASE and osgi.cmpn 5.0.0

Comment: It seems you are mixing spring versions. Show your pom, please.

Comment: i am using below spring jars   org.springframework.aop-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.beans-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.context-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.core-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.expression-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.orm-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.tx-3.2.14.jar,
  org.springframework.web-3.2.14.jar,
  osgi.cmpn-6.0.0.jar,                                                               
  org.my batis.mybatis-3.3.0.jar

Comment: Did you get a solution to this @sandy I am facing same issue. In builds fine on local machine and when deployed to AWS ECS, it throws this same error.

Comment: I was unable to find the root cause of this at that time so I did a workaround for that, registered bean using bundle activator instead of spring.